# Adding/Removing an element and updating its attribute via AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I'm building a small app that will allow a user to add/remove students from a course.  Every time i add/remove a course the database is updated and i update the total number of courses for the user.  When i add a student to a course it works fine, but when I go to remove them I am returned a 0 (from my PHP model function).  I believe it could be a problem with the jquery, i think i might need to use clone?  So I'm sorry for such a long post just wanted to make sure you guys have enough code to look at.
Here is my jQuery code that adds and removes the user to the course:

```
function addUserToClass(user)
{

 //creates the a data string to send to the controller with the user's id and the course id
 var postString = "courseid="+$("#course option:selected").val()+"&uid="+user.find('input').val();

 //adds the user to the course list in the database
 $.post('index.php/admin/addUserToCourse',postString);

  $("#courseList").append(user);
  $('#courseList .addUser').text('(-)').removeClass('addUser').addClass('removeUser'); 
}

//removes a user from the selected course in the database as well as on the screen
function removeUserFromClass(user)
{
 var postString = "courseid="+$("#course option:selected").val()+"&uid="+user.find('input').val();

 //removes the user fromt the course in the database
 $.post('admin/removeUserFromCourse',postString);

 $(user).remove();
 $('#usertable').append(user);
 $('#usertable .removeUser').text('(+)').removeClass('removeUser').addClass('addUser'); 



}
```

Here is my jQuery that updates the number of courses they are in:

```
function updateUserCourses(uid)
{
var postString = 'uid='+uid.siblings(':input').val();

  $.post('index.php/admin/getUsersCourses', postString , function(data){

   data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   uid.siblings('.internalCounter').text(data.internal);
   uid.siblings('.externalCounter').text(data.external);

  })

}
```

Not sure if you need this but my PHP (codeigniter controller) being called is:

```
 function getUsersCourses()
 {
  $this->load->model('course_model');
  $courses = $this->course_model->getUsersCourses($_POST['uid']);

  echo json_encode($courses);

 }
```

And my model function:

```
  function getUsersCourses($uid)
     {
      $external = array();
      $internal = array();
      $final = array();
      //Selects all of the courses the user has been added to
      $usersCourses = $this->db->query("SELECT courseid FROM final_course_list WHERE uid='{$uid}'");

  //If they have courses, proceed to process them
  if ($usersCourses->num_rows() > 0)
  {
   //For every course they have, we get the category of the course
   foreach($usersCourses->result() as $row)
   {
    $courseCat = $this->db->query("SELECT category FROM courses WHERE id = '{$row->courseid}'")->row_array();

    if($courseCat['category'] == 'External Topics')
    {
     array_push($external, $courseCat);
    }
    else if($courseCat['category'] == 'Internal Topics')
    {
     array_push($internal, $courseCat);
    }
   }

   //adds the internal and external amount of classes to one array
   $final['internal'] = count($internal);
   $final['external'] = count($external);
   $result = $final;
  }
  else
  {
   $result = 0;
  }

  return $result;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `removeUserFromClass` read:

```
$.post('index.php/admin/removeUserFromCourse',postString);
```

Comment: i doubled checked and its the correct name, i call the removeUserFromClass() in an event listener(not listed here).  Thanks for your help and pointing out my inconsistent naming conventions.

Comment: @dan: I meant that you are missing `index.php/` in your url...is it solved now?

Comment: you are right i was missing an index.php which was giving me a 500 error, I fixed that but it still isn't updating.  I still get a 0 returned to me which seems to be coming from my model not coming up with any query results.

Comment: @dan: so you are calling `updateUserCourses` after removing the user? because the `$.post` in `removeUserFromClass` is not returning anything. can you make sure that `uid` is actually sending something? also, can you confirm that the `removeUserFromClass` is actually deleting from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is worse than stupid mistakes that take forever to fix.  I don't think there was anything wrong with my JS it was my PHP model.  Instead of returning 0 i needed to return an the array

`array("internal"=>0,"external"=>0);`